# Uploadify not uploading all files in the queue automatically

Tags: jquery, uploadify

I have a problem with uploadify where it will not automatically upload all files in the queue. Either I am not adding them to the queue properly, or I am missing something. When I click the upload button, I really want all the files in the queue to be uploaded, but instead, I have to click the upload button everytime one is finished being uploaded.

button code:

```
<div id="some_file_queue"></div>
<input type="file" name="batchImport" id="batchImport"/>
<input type="button" class="batchImport" value="Upload Files">
```

javascript:

```
$("#batchImport").uploadify({
                'queueSizeLimit':10,
                'queueID':'some_file_queue',
                "swf":"/js/uploadify-v3.1/uploadify.swf",
                "uploader":"/js/uploadify-v3.1/uploadify.php",
                "uploadFolder":"/uploads/",
                "auto":false,
                "multi":true,
                "height":19,
                "width":94,
                "onUploadError":function(file,errorCode,errorMsg,errorString){
                    alert("The file " + file.name + " could not be uploaded: " + errorString);
                },
                "onQueueComplete":function(queueData){
                    console.log(queueData);
                },
                "onUploadSuccess":function(file, data, response){
                    $.ajax({
                        type:"POST",
                        data:{
                            single:1,
                            file:file,
                            data:data,
                            call:'element',
                            objContainer:$('select[name="objContainer"] option:selected').val()
                        },
                        url:"/index.php/upload_handler/handler",
                        success:function(response){
                            checkResponse(response);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });

            $(document).on("click",".batchImport",function(){
                $("#batchImport").uploadifyUpload("*");
            });
```

Answer (score 2):

if you set auto:true as per:
http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/uploadify/auto/
files will be uploaded automatically.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for:

```
$("#batchImport").uploadify('upload','*');
```

[Live DEMO](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/uploadify/upload/) on uploadify's site.

Answer (score -1):

You should place "auto":true, in your javascript code.. then its work..

$("#batchImport").uploadify({
                'queueSizeLimit':10,
                'queueID':'some_file_queue',
                "swf":"/js/uploadify-v3.1/uploadify.swf",
                "uploader":"/js/uploadify-v3.1/uploadify.php",
                "uploadFolder":"/uploads/",
                **"auto":true,**
                "multi":true,
                "height":19,
                "width":94,
                "onUploadError":function(file,errorCode,errorMsg,errorString){
                    alert("The file " + file.name + " could not be uploaded: " + errorString);
                },
                "onQueueComplete":function(queueData){
                    console.log(queueData);
                },
                "onUploadSuccess":function(file, data, response){
                    $.ajax({
                        type:"POST",
                        data:{
                            single:1,
                            file:file,
                            data:data,
                            call:'element',
                            objContainer:$('select[name="objContainer"] option:selected').val()
                        },
                        url:"/index.php/upload_handler/handler",
                        success:function(response){
                            checkResponse(response);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });

```
        $(document).on("click",".batchImport",function(){
            $("#batchImport").uploadifyUpload("*");
        });
```